# Inserting text into a stream using Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

Good day, which adds to the video stream and sends the text back into the stream. The idea is that I want the program to listen to certain IP addresses and port stream, using the OpenCV library, this stream divided into frames and each frame inserted text and then re-imposed in the stream. I need to do this in python. Input and output stream will use the H.264 codec. Here I found the code in python which can thus adjust the video, but I needed to do this from the stream. Please advise.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
capture = cv2.VideoCapture("simpsnovi,prilis_drsne_pro_tv_03.avi")

flag, frame = capture.read()
width = np.size(frame, 1)
height = np.size(frame, 0)
#fourcc=cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('I', 'Y', 'U', 'V'), #this is the codec that works for me
writer = cv2.VideoWriter(filename="your_writing_file.avi", 
fourcc=cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D'), #this is the codec that works for me

fps=25, #frames per second, I suggest 15 as a rough initial estimate
frameSize=(width, height))

while True:
    flag, frame = capture.read()
    if flag == 0:
        break
    x = width/2
    y = height/2
    text_color = (255,0,0)
    cv2.putText(frame, "your_string", (x,y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, text_color, thickness=1,linetype=cv2.CV_AA)
    writer.write(frame)
```

Comment: what you mean about stream can you explain more , did you mean live video like capture from webcam ? thanks !

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need **UDP** socket server! That server will listen on some IP and PORT for you. Then, you can work with OpenCV.

Comment: That does not answer my question. The code above works with the video file I want to work with-stream!!

Answer (score 0):

**this code work with linux webcam ! that i have been written 9 month ago for detect corners ! so for you i add a puttext on it !**
also i delete the index `linetype` because my opencv raise an error and dont accept it!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#set the width and height, and UNSUCCESSFULLY set the exposure time
cap.set(3,1080)
cap.set(4,1024)
cap.set(15, 0.1)
flag, frame = cap.read()
width = np.size(frame, 1)
height = np.size(frame, 0)

def corner(filename) : 
 im= filename

 gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

 corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray,25,0.01,10)
 corners = np.int0(corners)

 for i in corners:
    x,y = i.ravel()
    cv2.circle(img,(x,y),3,(0,0,255),-1)
 return im

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    #gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
    #thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,1,1,11,2)
    x = width/2
    y = height/2
    text_color = (255,0,0)
    cv2.putText(img, "your_string", (x,y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, text_color, thickness=1)
    cv2.imshow("input",corner(img))
    #cv2.imshow("thresholded", imgray*thresh2)

    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == 27:
        break


cv2.destroyAllWindows() 
cv2.VideoCapture(0).release()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its way too late, but to answer your question, you can change the video source on your VideoCapture class with the address of your stream. Ex.:

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture("http://192.168.1.1/stream/video.mjpeg")
```

Take note that you have to include the actual file name + format being used in the stream.